# Cannot get a field on DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to display the name to the appbar but userid part seems like giving an error. iam a beginner to flutter and firestore can someone help me

```
class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
}

class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
  //To retrieve the Userid
  User? user;
  Future<void> getUserData() async {
    User userData = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
    setState(() {
      user = userData;
      print(userData.uid);
    });
  }
///////////////////////////////////////

  Future<String>? _title;
  @override
  void initState() {
    getUserData().then((value) => _title = _getAppBarNameWidget());
    // _title = _getAppBarNameWidget();
    super.initState();
  }

//To retrieve the name from firestore
  Future<String> _getAppBarNameWidget() async =>
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('customer')
          .doc(user!.uid)
          .get()
          .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) async {
        var name = ds['name'];
        return name;
      });
```

Comment: can u show your error msg

Comment: StateError (Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist)

Comment: are u sure u r type corrent key name

Comment: Yes in the place .doc(user!.uid) if i give like .doc('Xk1eUAfdSMqp7rpwYxc4') this with direct uid it works

Comment: inside setState when u r print is it uid is printed

Comment: Yes its printed

Comment: then make a new var and insetState change the value of UId there and use it when u call firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DocumentSnapshot ds` does not directly contain document data, only document **id**, you have to use `data()` function to get data. It is also a good idea to check whether the document really exists, because you will get a snapshot event if the document is not found.

Examples:

```
ds.exists          // will return true if document is found
ds.id              // will return document reference
ds.data()!['name'] // will return 'name' field of document
```

Comment: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '[]'   . im getting this error for the 3e=rd one

Comment: Made it thanks i was having 2 collections

Comment: Ok, good to hear. If it is an object (if you use a fromJson converter for example) than it simply use it with dot: `.name` instead of `['name']`.