# (Flutter Firestore) Field does not exist within DocumentSnapshotPlatform

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting an error when trying to retrieve data from a subcollection. The firestore db is as follows -> users; doc uid; messages; loans approved; loans approved.

I have double checked that I typed the doc and collections correctly so what am I missing?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you

[image: firestore screenshot]

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class MessagesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MessagesScreenState createState() => MessagesScreenState();
}

FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final uid = _auth.currentUser!.uid;
var boldFont = TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Inter', fontWeight: FontWeight.w600);

class MessagesScreenState extends State<MessagesScreen> {
  final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(uid)
      .collection('Messages')
      .snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          titleSpacing: 30,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(1, 67, 55, 1),
          toolbarHeight: 100,
          title: new Text(
            'Messages',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1),
                fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                fontSize: 25,
                letterSpacing: 1.2,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                height: 1),
          ),
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: db,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData)
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return snapshot.data!.docs[index]['Loans approved']
                      ['Loans overdue']['Loans paid'];
                });
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check my recent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69366803/cannot-get-a-field-on-documentsnapshotplatform-which-does-not-exist/69367551#69367551). Basically field data will be under `docs[index].data()!`.

Comment: When I do it like this I get this error: The operator '[Loans approved]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.

Comment: It seems that you have a fromJson converter and therefore is is already an object here. Print out or stop with breakpoint, and check what's in `docs[index].data()!`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner with flutter so I'm not sure how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you define the Stream (your `db` variable) as

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(uid)
      .collection('Messages')
      .snapshots();
```

Based on your screenshot, there is one `Loans approved` document in this `Messages` collection which does not have any data. This document has a `Loans approved` subcollection which, in turns, contains a `Loans approved` document. It is this doc that contains the fields (`Interest`, `Loan amount`, etc.).

So defining your Stream as follow should do the trick:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(uid)
      .collection('Messages')
      .doc('Loans approved')
      .collection('Loans approved')
      .snapshots();
```

---

PS: I would advise you to use the [camelCase convention](https://dev.to/prahladyeri/underscores-camelcasing-and-pascalcasing-the-three-naming-conventions-every-programmer-should-be-aware-of-3aed) when writing collections, docs and field names.

Comment: The error went away but now I am getting a blank screen with no data returned after circle progress indicator fires

Comment: Which exact field value(s) do  you want to get? In your code we can see `['Loans approved']`, `['Loans overdue']`or `['Loans paid']` but none of these seem to be a field of a document (at least from what we can see in your screenshot). Try doing `return snapshot.data!.docs[index]['Loan amount'];`

Comment: Ok I just tried returning ```snapshot.data!.docs[index]['Loan amount'];``` I still get a blank screen. The circle progress indicator is still firing and then nothing loads after that.

Comment: As a debugging exercise, can you try to implement the [example](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes) we find in the doc, i.e. `return ListView(children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;...`?